# Pulp Solvers - Python 3.8 & Spyder 4

Tags: python, solver, pulp, coin-or-cbc

I am using Pulp with Python 3.8 and Spyder 4.

I am able to run optimization problems without issues, but I am not able to change the parameters of the solvers. Indeed, no solver seems to be recognized by Pulp.

When I enter

`my_lp_problem.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD())`

I have the error :

name 'PULP_CBC_CMD' is not defined

How can I manage this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: please add a minimal working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If you get a `NameError` (i.e., name 'PULP_CBC_CMD' is not defined) it's because you have not imported the `pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD` class.

The solution is either to import it

```
from pulp import PULP_CBC_CMD
```

or to specify the pulp module

```
my_lp_problem.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD())
```